# Projection of finite set of points on sphere preserving distances up to scale

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry

Let $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n \in \mathbb{R}^p$ such that $\|x_i\|_2 \leq 1$. Does there exist $P: \mathbb{R}^q \to \mathbb{R}^p$, $q \geq p$, $\lambda > 0$ and $y_1, \ldots, y_n$ such that:

- $\|y_i\|_2 = 1$
- $P(y_i) = x_i$
- $\|y_i - y_j\|_2 = \lambda \cdot \|x_i - x_j\|_2$
- $P$ linear

The problem asks whether for any set of points within a unit hypersphere, there exists a set of points on the unit hypersphere in a higher dimensional space that projects onto the original points and preserves the scale of pairwise distances.

Comment: SInce $P(y_i) = x_i$, shouldn't we have $\lambda = 1$?

Comment: @Youem I think the third condition should have $|| y_i - y_j ||$ instead of $||P(y_i) - P(y_j)||$.

Comment: @ronno that makes sense.

Comment: @Youem Thanks for spotting the error.